# Need to remove key from UIKeyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikeyboard

I need to remove specific keys from the keyboard. I've looked around a lot and I have found how to add custom keys and how to remove them. However, I need to remove a built in key.  Let's say for example I want to remove the a key from the keyboard.

The following code just removes the whole keyboard from the view which is not what I'm looking for.

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification {        
    for (UIWindow *keyboardWindow in [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows]) 
    {   
        // Now iterating over each subview of the available windows
        for (UIView *keyboard in [keyboardWindow subviews]) {   
            // Check to see if the description of the view we have 
            // referenced is UIKeyboard.
            // If so then we found the keyboard view that we were looking for.
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)                    
                [[keyboard.subviews objectAtIndex:0]removeFromSuperview];                
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure the subview of keyboard window i

Answer (score 0):

You'd be best to make a custom keyboard and just add the keys you want, rather than trying to change the built in keyboard, which is likely to break or cause problems with approval. Here are some examples:

http://brygruver.squarespace.com/blog/2009/10/1/creating-a-custom-number-pad.html

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/7350-adding-subviews-custimize-keyboard.html